# Google Api - Curl Request - missing required authentication credential error

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to make simple cURL request:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization:  ".$getUserData['access_token'].""
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

I get the following error:

```
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully made the request using curl from the command line? That would be something like:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer _token_" https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts
```

You also do not appear to have the correct header, which would requires the word "Bearer" as defined in the [RFC in section 7.1.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749)

[Google's API documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest) features this section, highlighting just such usage:

```
GET /drive/v2/files HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer access_token
```